# Calculate average for the those who meet a certain criteria

Tags: reporting-services, average

I'm trying to calculate the average for only particular records

For example, we have a field called `FurthestSlide`.  This field will contain numbers.  We have another field called `SlideCount`.  This is also a number field.

I only want it to calculate the average for the records where the `FurthestSlide` does not equal the `SlideCount` number.

What I am trying to find is the average `FurthestSlide` number for those people who did not view the entire message.

I do not want those who finished the message to be calculated in the data.

Sample Data:

```
SlideCount=40
FurthestSlide=(30,20,40,40,40)
```

The answer should come out to **25**. (30+20)/2

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude certain rows from an aggregate.

With your data:

[image]

And a simple report:

[image]

I have calculated the average for non-matching rows with the expression:

```
=Avg(IIf(Fields!FurthestSlide.Value <> Fields!SlideCount.Value
  , Fields!FurthestSlide.Value
  , Nothing))
```

Here we set matched rows `FurthestSlide` value as `Nothing`, which means they are excluded from any average calculation.

This gives the required result for your data:

[image]